# Admob stopped receiving revenue when I signed my apk

Tags: android, google-play, admob

I stopped receiving impressions and revenue when I signed the apk since I uploaded it in Google Play Store. When using a debug apk It can generate small amount of impression from me but after signing it and publishing it on google play store it stopped generating revenue.

What should I do here?

Comment: debug apk can not generate any impressions

Comment: it does generate impression.